# Make text from external file uppercase

Tags: input, capitalization

I would like to do something like

```
\uppercase{\input{filename}}
```

so that the text in the file `filename` is printed uppercase.

(Above command complains about `FILENAME.tex` not to exist, apparently `\uppercase` is applied before `\input` is expended.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's a use case for this?

Comment: @egreg I have some text that is used in my latex document (where in some cases it should be uppercase) but also used by other programs that process it (that's why in external files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the file with `catchfile` and then apply `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-touc.tex}
This will be printed uppercase
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\ucinput}[1]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\ucinputtemp}{#1}{}%
  \MakeUppercase{\ucinputtemp}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text and \ucinput{\jobname-touc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `filecontents*` environment is just for convenience; any file can be used in this way. But the text in the input file has several limitations. A one-liner should be OK.